# Remove internal indexed pages from Google search

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing

I received a Wordpress site created as a one-page site. The site has a menu to access different blocks with an url hash: `example.com/#about-as`.

The problem is that Google indexed different contents, like attachments and not relevant content and worst, with numbers as title (due to file image name):

[image]

Now, I added a sitemap, with only the home page on it.

My main goal now is these internal links to be removed.

As a secondary goal, is it possible to create a similar index structure setting sitemap with these links to home page with its different hashes?

Thank you.

Comment: Your sitemap has almost no bearing on what Google indexes.  Google can discover content from an XML sitemap file, and can use sitemaps to choose canonical URLs.   However, sitemaps won't cause Google to index pages included in them or to not index pages not included in them. See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!

Comment: How about removing those "internal links" and showing only main site on Google results?